# jenkins stop subjob completely when multijob phase is failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multijob phase with two jobs. I added condition "Mark phase as successful" when "Successful", But when one job fails it is not stopping another job. Simply coming out and executing post-build actions.


How can i stop remaining jobs completely when one job failed in same phase?


Is there any way to stop a job from post-build actions?

Example:
MultiJob
   - Phase 1
      - Job1
      - Job2
   - Phase 2
      - Job3
      - Job4

If 'Job1' is failed in Phase1, It won't continue for next and makes build as failed. But i want to stop 'Job2' if 'Job1' fails.

Comment: Just wondering what you mean with multijob phase. Please explain your setup in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this, We have "PostBuildScript" plugin in jenkins. With this we can add a post build action and select any script to execute.

I have selected groovy script to do it. Following script will stop the jobs left from MultiJob.

```
    import hudson.model.*
    import jenkins.model.Jenkins
    for(c in Jenkins.instance.computers) {
      println("computer: "+c.name)
      for(e in c.executors) {
        println("name: "+e.name)
        if (e.name =~ /JOBNAME/){
          println("JOB : "+e.name)
          e.interrupt();
        }
      }
    }
```

look at this "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin"